# PHP e mysql contagem de horas

Tags: php, mysql, data

Boa noite,

Sou novo aqui.

Uma dúvida acho que é básica.

Vou criar uma "aplicação" com PHP e mysql onde controlo as horas de trabalho de cada colaborador com entradas e saídas diárias. 
A dúvida é o SQL apenas armazena os dados quem faz o "trabalho de contagem é o PHP no caso ?
para trabalhar com esse tipo de datas onde o objetivo é contar as horas de trabalho semanais e mensais que tipo de dado utilizo no mysql o tipo DATE ou string e no php faço o casting ?

Desde já agradeço a atenção

Answer (score 2):

Irei dividir as perguntas para melhor responder, então depois resolver o problema (ou sugerir uma solução) ao caso.

> O MySQL apenas armazena e quem "faz o trabalho" é o PHP no caso?

Sim e não. O MySQL é muito mais do que somente um `SELECT coluna FROM`, você pode somar, subtrair, concatenar (...) e várias e várias outras operações. Muitas pessoas, eu incluso, recomendam sempre usar as funções do MySQL em relação a processa-los no PHP, quando possível.

**Exemplo:**

Calcular total de "Ganhos" da tabela "Financeiro" onde "1 = 1" (ou seja, tudo).

**Usando MySQL:**

```
$query = mysqli_query($sql, SELECT sum(Ganhos) FROM financeiro WHERE 1 = 1);
list($total) = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

echo $total;
```

Resposta:

```
100
```

Você não precisa ficar fazendo um loop de cada valor para obter a soma de tudo, a soma pode ser feita pelo `SUM()`. :)

> Qual tipo de dado utilizo no MySQL? O tipo DATE ou string e no php faço o casting?

É sempre melhor que use aquilo que foi designado a ele. Justamente para que possa fazer uso das funções nativas do MySQL. No exemplo anterior, se o campo "Ganhos" fosse um VARCHAR seria "impossível" usar o `sum()`, ou seja seria impossível somar os dados via MySQL. *Para usar o `sum()` nessa condição teria que usar o `cast()` e ainda poderia ter erros em casos de alguns valores nulos, convenhamos que escolher o INT seria melhor do que um VARCHAR, nesse caso do exemplo.*

Você pode usar "VARCHAR para tudo" desde que abra mão de todos os recursos que o MySQL (ou outro banco de dados qualquer) possa oferecer, ou necessitar de "gambiarras" e mais códigos para conseguir usa-los. É logico que alguns casos pode haver mais de um campo a ser escolhido, uma data pode se optar por DATETIME ou TIMESTAMP e pode optar por INT ou BIGINT. No geral, o escolher "erradamente" também pode ter custo de processamento e performance em geral.

### Resolvendo o seu problema

Imagine essa tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE tempo
    (`id` int, `usuario` varchar(32), `dataEntrada` int(11), `dataSaida` int(11))
;
```

Imagine esses dados:

```
INSERT INTO tempo
    (`id`, `usuario`, `dataEntrada`, `dataSaida`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Inkeliz', '1451638800', '1451671200'),
    (2, 'Thiago', '1451638800', '1451667600'),
    (3, 'Inkeliz', '1451721600', '1451764800')
;
```

Os dados de `dataEntrada` e `dataSaida` estão em UNIX TIME, isso é medido em segundos desde 01/01/1970, salvo engano. Por isso estou a usar o `INT`, porque os dados serão inserido como:

```
mysqli_query($sql, 'UPDATE dataSaida SET dataSaida = "'.time().'" WHERE id = (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM tempo WHERE usuario = "Thiago" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as x)');
```

Isso irá obter o último `id` onde o usuário é `Thiago`, então atualizar o horário de saída. O horário de entrada seria definido pelo `INSERT` anteriormente.

Para você ver por exemplo, o número de horas trabalhadas poderá usar:

```
$tempoTrabalho = mysqli_query($sql, 'SELECT usuario, TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(ABS(`dataSaida`- `dataEntrada`))),"%H Horas %i Minutos") FROM tempo WHERE dataSaida != 0 GROUP BY usuario');

foreach(mysqli_fetch_all($tempoTrabalho) as list($usuario, $tempo)){

    echo $usuario.' trabalhou por '.$tempo;
    echo '<br>';

}
```

Resultado:

```
Inkeliz trabalhou por 21 Horas 00 Minutos
Thiago trabalhou por 08 Horas 00 Minutos
```

> Esse exemplo pode ser complexo para quem está começando no MySQL/PHP!

A grande diferença desse código é que todo o trabalho é feito pelo MySQL, o PHP apenas tem o trabalho de exibir os dados, "como está".

Como a função está concentrada na query do MySQL, aqui está ela separada:

```
SELECT 
usuario, 
TIME_FORMAT(
  SEC_TO_TIME(
    SUM(
      ABS(`dataSaida`- `dataEntrada`)
    )
  ),'%H Horas %i Minutos') 

[...]

GROUP BY 
usuario
```

> [Veja no SQL Fiddle!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e53f1/8/0)

Explicações, de dentro para fora:

No SELECT:

[`ABS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) = Retorna o valor bruto (1 - 100 = 99).

[`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) = Somará o resultado de todos os (`A` + `B`) baseado no [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html).

[`SEC_TO_TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) = Converterá os segundos (retornados do SUM) para HH:MM:SS.

[`TIME_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) = Irá entregar os dados (HH:MM:SS) no formato "0 Horas 0 Minutos".

Em resumo o MySQL é muito mais do que armazenar dados, como sugeriu. Nesse caso o PHP apenas teve o trabalho de exibir os dados, nenhum calculo foi feito por ele.

Comment: Muito bom, aprendi bastante.;)